# Registering Custom WMI C# class/event

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I have a project with a class that extend a WMI event and used to publish data through WMI. the class look like this (just few rows of the entire class):

```
[InstrumentationClass(InstrumentationType.Instance)]
public class PointInstrumentation
{
    private bool enabled = true;

    // static data
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string EffectiveUserName { get; set; }
    public string Environment { get; set; }
    public string Universe { get; set; }
    public int AppProcessId { get; set; }
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    public string AppHostName { get; set; }
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string OrbAddress { get; set; }
    public string ApiVersion { get; set; }
```

..

```
     public void Publish()
    {

            System.Management.Instrumentation.Instrumentation.Publish(this);
```

..

as you can see, its extends using attribute declation "[InstrumentationClass(InstrumentationType.Instance)]"

my issue is that when i register the dll, i don't see PointInstrumentation class in the WMI explorer, hence, i can't query what is being published.

Can anyone please explain me what am i doing wrong and what the appropriate way to register WMI (c#) classes.

Thanks